# How can I improve my SA algorithm that I used for job scheduling?

Tags: algorithm, simulated-annealing, operations-research

```
 objective: max sum(solution(i,9))
---------------------------------------------
 while T>Tmin
  for iteration=100
    for i=1:61
       function(generate_possible_solutions)
       random_value = generate random value
       solution(i) = generate_possible_solution(random_value, :)
       feasible = sum(solution(i, 9))
    next

    SA:
        check feasible
        if feasible > previous_feasible
           update best
        else 
           check acceptance function
        end
        if iteration == limit
           update (T)
        end

   end For

end While
```

Code is above.

I have a problem with job scheduling. My heuristic algorithm uses possible_solution matrix to allocate each job to a line. For example, 6th job has 140 different options, 7th has 30 different options in the possible_solution matrix.

In simulated annealing, in each iteration, I use one of the solution line into the possible_solution matrix randomly. However, the solution reaches 50% at most when it is compared to GAMS/Cplex solver.

May I use the random selection from solution matrix to use Simulated Annealing? and what I have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SA:

- It is OK to start with any random starting state (`S`). It should not have a large effect on solution as in the initial phase of annealing most random proposals are accepted, because we start with a high temperature `T`. So it is OK to use any random start state, also ransom selection from solution matrix.
- During annealing, you slightly modify the current starte `S`. Don't randomly pick a new state `Q`, but slightly modify `S`, say `S*`.
- With condition, check of enforce that `S*` is within feasible region. Either only modify such that it is feasible, or fix any violations afterwards.
- Try pick neighbours states `*S` that make sense. Mimic what humans would do to improve a current situation, e.g; pick a random job that is not scheduled well and randomly re-allocate resources. Randomly pick a resource might also work.
- Should starting `T` such that most proposals (>90%) are accepted. Use debug during annealing to get some feeling of proportion accepted states. Similarly chose `T_stop` when almost no new states are accepted.
- After `T_start` and `T_stop` are acceptable, start experimenting with different proposals. They have large effect on quality of solution. (Cooling scheme just to geometric, i.e. `T = T * alpha` with `0 < alpha < 1`.

Comment: Thank you for your guide. Actually, for each iteration into the temperature, I generate random list. However, I did not change solution s slightly to s*. It will require algorithm change as I understand truly.Thanks again, now I will check how I can produce s* with changing slightly last solution s. for example. I generate for 3 jobs to get into oven early as 10 min, 5 min. 6 min. respectively. So, I generate for other iteration, 6 min. 3 min. 9 min.respectively. Does it provide neighbor solution or am I wrong?

Comment: Now, I changed the algorithm check. Normally, algorithm checks delay_saving for each job randomly, but if it is possible, it selects above 15 min. within iteration limit. Now, to provide this change slightly, I added condition. It will provide for each job's delay_saving will be changed between -5 min or +5 min. If it is not possible during the iteration limit, algorithm generates random one for the job. So, I expect the change for each job's delay saving slight. But, I am confused now that I manipulate the solution process to increase the performance.

Comment: Yes you are at the right track- indeed play with variations of current state like for 1..3 jobs randomly change something sensible.

Check with debug information everything works as expected: print the current objective function, change in objective function, print the probability to be accepted as next state, and print T. Also vary start/stop T.

Comment: Hello again, I tried to go through with select 1 job and changing its delaySaving between lower & upper bound. However, it goes worse ine ach iteration due to constraints. What do you think about this idea? Does it make a neighbor solution?  --> If I determine lower and upper bound for a new solution, for example initial solution = 200, then I define that new solution in each iteration +- 10 than previousSolution, does it save the Local Search? So, I will generate random solution and I will control the sum of delaySavings according to the rule of neighbor, +- 10 than previousSolution.

Comment: Can you try to describe a small toy example? Few jobs, few resources, that could scale up to (almost) your problem?

Comment: ok, I have 61 jobs to bake in an oven. They have starting time, finished time, capacity constraints due to oven capacity. I try to give some earlier starting time to reduce delay of each breads for example.  I can give a bread at any time to the oven. And oven capacity 5. So, I get a result which control the randomness with for-loop step size of delay savings between 0-40.

Comment: Then, I choose a job no, i.e. 30, before 30.job all jobs have same delay savings with previous solution, however after 30.job will change to get a neighbor under constraints. Now I succeed to get neighbor as you explain before. Thanks for it. For example, I found 485 min. delay savings, now I run the code it is changing between 400 - 420, however, the GAMS/Cplex found it 601 min.

Comment: I let delay savings changes between -10 to 10 bound limits from previous value of job(i). But, due to constraints, if they cannot made to remain between this boundaries, I gave them some delay to keep the solution feasible under constraints. If I solve the TSP, it is basic I can swap two cities and then go on with better or worse but close to preivous one without constraints codes. However, with constraints, it is difficult to shape an elegant iteration X delay_savings graph to show the gradual improvements. All Solutions is distributed mostly everywhere in the graph:D

Comment: I think I understand. Some questions to verify: Are all ovens the same? (In capacity and types)? Does it seem a good strategy to maximize the ovens operation time, for each oven? (This can be a proxy for the objective) - Are all bread to bake similar expect for prefix time, time in oven, and postfix time?

Comment: There is one oven with 5 slot in it. So, max. 5 breads can be baked. all breads have different cooked durations so, each one may go out of the oven with different times. any bread can be get into oven iff one bread goes out of the oven. So, waiting for a bread inside creates delays due to oven capacity. I try to give some earliness for breads to minimize total tardiness. So, when I determine neighbor distance lowerbound = 1, upperbound=1 in terms of delay savings of each job (i), it stucks very local max. area.

Comment: When I play with bounds it changes the solutions however not close more than 70% to the GAMS/Cplex however, my heuristic is approaching to GAMS/Cplex solver by 85%. 70% is acceptable for SA or poor efficiency.?

Comment: So a valid planning is 5 lists of unique jobs, representing 5 slots. The objective_function will calculate all times the oven will be openend, and each time during opening remove and add new job/bread.

During annealing you could swap jobs within a slot, or swap jobs from/to different slots. Seems about right?